# Nginx allow ip to access all paths

Tags: nginx, ip

Is there any way to allow an ip to access all paths and files on the server?

I mean really any path or file.

Because i have some problems with mono that it tells me that my file is forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this, but it's really not recommended, especially if this is a live/production website. You simple have to set autoindex to all for the root path. Setup your list of addresses with geo and an if statement.

```
geo $allow_addresses {
    default 0;
    144.0.0.0/24 1;
}

    server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
            access_log  /var/log/access.log;
            root   /path/to/root;
            location / {
                    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            }
            location / {
                if ($internals) {
                    autoindex on;
                }
             }

    }
```